# With pytest is it possible to write 'generic' test cases (rather than parametrized)?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures, testcase

Imagine a `test_` function which doesn't implement a test directly but loads instructions from files:

```
$ tree tests 
tests
├── scenario1
├── scenario2
└── scenario3
```

```py
def test_generic(file):
    for file in Path("tests").iterdir():
        execute_test(file)
```

This could be written in a more test-ish way using `parametrize`:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("file", (p.name for p in Path("tests").iterdir()))
def test_generic(file):
    execute_test(file)
```

Giving me distinct test items:

```
collected 3 items                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

test_me.py::test_generic[scenario1] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             [ 33%]
test_me.py::test_generic[scenario3] PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             [ 66%]
test_me.py::test_generic[scenario2] PASSED
```

Now here is the question: is it possible to turn `test_generic` into a truly generic test function? I.e. `scenario1..3` not being *parameters* to `test_generic` but individual tests (which themselves might be parametrized).

So in the end I'd like to have items like this:

```
collected 3 items                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

test_me.py::scenario1 PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             [ 33%]
test_me.py::scenario3 PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             [ 66%]
test_me.py::scenario2 PASSED
```

So what I'm looking for might look like

```
for file in Path("tests").iterdir():
    pytest.define_test(file.name, lambda f: execute_test(f))
```

(and would probably go to `conftest.py`?)